# Swift 4 - Action while button pressed - loop?

Tags: ios, swift, button, gesture

Hi i want to send a command to a motor at my raspberry while a button is pressed. So for example: While I press the button, the motor should run. It is a stepper motor, so I want long tap and normal tap commands. Normal tap is easy and work, but the long tap (repeatedly commands) doesn't work. I tried it with the long tap gesture recognizer and loops but it doesn't work
Here's my code.

```
@objc func motorLongTap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer){        
    while (sender.state == .began) && (sender.state != .ended){
    //send command
    }
}
```

The loop doesn't stop. Hope somebody can help me.
Best Regards

EDIT: Problem solved. 
Thank you MadProgrammer for your solution

Here is now the code to get a "loop" when action is pressed.

```
var buttonTimer:Timer!

@objc func motorLongTap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer){        
    if sender.state == .ended{
    buttonTimer.invalide()
    }
    else sender.state == .began{
    buttonTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(longTapMotor), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

}
    @objc func longTapMotor() {
        //send command
    }
```

Comment: You will need a "start" and "end" command, as you can't loop like that within the context of the main thread, it will prevent the UI from process new input events.  You could use another thread or a `Timer` which repeats at a set interval which you could invalidate when the touch event ends

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is incorrect. Try this:

```
@objc func motorLongTap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer){        
    if sender.state != .ended{
        //send command
    }
}
```